# Joining using column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, join

I'm having two dataframes in pandas, the one is initial one:

[image]

and the other is the result of `TF-IDF` operation. So basically, `Name` was grouped by `Group` and then `sklearn TF-IDF` was applied like that:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

frame = df.groupby(['Group'])['Name'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(frame)

yy=pd.DataFrame(tfidf.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
yy['Group']=frame['Group']
```

[image]

Right now I would like to join two dataframes (which, for sure, I can do using `merge()` using `Group` as ID) but I would like also to use column names from the second dataframe to join with respective values in `Name` column in first dataframe to construct something like that:

[image]

How can this be achieved in pandas and do I need to use for loops for completing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melt the 2nd data frame and then merge with the 1st one:

```
df2.melt('Group', var_name='Name', value_name='Res').merge(df1, how='right')

   Group Name  Res
0      1    A  0.0
1      1    A  0.0
2      2    A  0.0
3      2    B  0.1
4      3    B  0.0
5      3    C  0.1
```

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, I accidentally downvoted your answer yesterday, so I had to edit the answer  in order to upvote it since the vote was locked.